# How to deep copy a Builder component, such as TPanel, TButton etc

Tags: c++, c++builder

Does anybody know how to deep copy a builder component?

I was under the impression that I could use the Assign function as they don't have a copy constructor available?

I am using Assign but it doesn't like it for a TPanel (works OK for Graphics::TBitmap). The error I get is "Cannot assign a TPanel to a TPanel" ?

Does anybody have any ideas how I should be doing this? A snippet of code is as follows:

```
CConfigComponentPanel::CConfigComponentPanel( const CConfigComponentPanel& rkConfigComponentPanel ):
CConfigComponent( rkConfigComponentPanel ),
m_pkPanel( new TPanel(this) )
{
    m_pkPanel->Assign( rkConfigComponentPanel.m_pkPanel );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most VCL classes *do not* implement the `Assign()` or `AssignTo()` methods at all. Typically, only non-visual utility classes do (`TStringList`, `TFont`, `TGraphic` descendants, etc).  The only way to deep-copy a component, especially a visual one, is to use its RTTI to loop through its properties copying their values from one component instance to another component instace one at a time, recursively if child controls are present.  To help you with that, use the `TStream::WriteComponent()` and `TStream::ReadComponent()` methods to save a component and its children to, and read back from, a temporary in-memory DFM.  That way, the RTL handles the RTTI access for you. For example:

```
CConfigComponentPanel::CConfigComponentPanel( const CConfigComponentPanel& rkConfigComponentPanel )
    : CConfigComponent( rkConfigComponentPanel ), m_pkPanel( new TPanel(this) ) 
{ 
    TMemoryStream *Strm = new TMemoryStream;
    try
    {
        Strm->WriteComponent( rkConfigComponentPanel.m_pkPanel );
        Strm->Position = 0;
        Strm->ReadComponent( m_pkPanel );
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete Strm;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
CConfigComponentPanel::CConfigComponentPanel( const CConfigComponentPanel& rkConfigComponentPanel )
    : CConfigComponent( rkConfigComponentPanel ), m_pkPanel( NULL ) 
{ 
    TMemoryStream *Strm = new TMemoryStream;
    try
    {
        Strm->WriteComponent( rkConfigComponentPanel.m_pkPanel );
        Strm->Position = 0;
        m_pkPanel = (TPanel*) Strm->ReadComponent( NULL );
        InsertComponent( m_pkPanel );
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete Strm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer that makes a lot of sense. However when running this code I get a 'Class TPanel not found' error? I read somewhere that I should call RegisterClass but this causes a compilation error? I am using Borland C++ Builder 2007. I also got an error when trying to use the InsertComponent function, unless this is a function that I need to write?

Comment: If `TPanel` were truely not found, then `rkConfigComponentPanel.m_pkPanel` could not be instantiated at runtime, either (assuming it is a component placed on a `TForm` at designtime). Design-time components are registered automatically at runtime so they can be found during DFM streaming. `InsertComponent()` is a method of `TComponent`. Presumably, since you were originally passing `this` as the Owner for `m_pkPanel`, then `CConfigComponentPanel` is a `TComponent` descendant.  The `TComponent.Create()` constructor calls `AOwner.InsertComponent(Self)` internally.

Comment: If you are having compiler errors, then please show them. They mean you have bugs in your code.

Comment: Hi, My component is part of a class which is not a dfm. I think this is what is causing me a problem. I think that my design is going to have to change to resolve this issue as it is probably telling me that the design is not quite right in the first place. I am using the VCL in a way that it is not intended to be used. To resolve the issue I have used a pointer instead of an instance so that my copy constructor never gets called, thus avoiding the need for a deep copy. Thank you all for your help as I have learnt a few new things. Joe